# I want to hide a specific navigation bar based on user role

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, sweetalert

I am having hard time hiding a specific nav bar when the user is succefully log in as admin,I want to hide the navigation bar class named "ordertrackingClass" when the user is log in as admin. here's my code.

```
function validateUser(){
 enteredUsername = $("#usernameSignIn").val();
 enteredPassword = $("#passwordSignIn").val();

var users = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("userRecord"));

for(i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
    if(enteredUsername == users[i].Username && enteredPassword == users[i].Password){

        if(users[i].AccessType == "1"){
        swal({title: "Log in Successful!", text: "Log in as customer", icon: 
            "success"});



        }else if(users[i].AccessType == "2"){
         swal({title: "Log in Successful!", text: "Log in as Staff", icon: 
            "success"});
        }else if(users[i].AccessType == "3"){

            swal({title: "Log in Successfully!", text: "Log in as Admin", icon: 
            "success"}).then(function(){ 
             window.location = "Home.html"
             $('li.orderTrackingClass').hide();
            }
        ); //end of swal

        }
      return;
    }

}
swal({title: "Log in Failed!", text: "Incorrect credentials", icon: 
            "error"});
```

Comment: You are navigating to a different page (`Home.html`) before hiding the navigation bar. This means that the line `$('li.orderTrackingClass').hide();` is never executed. You need to check the `user.AccessType` during the loading of `Home.html`.

Comment: Can please explain it more further?